# Window not fully filled with specific background color - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Recently i've been trying to make a simple GUI with tkinter in python
but for some reason the background color doesn't fully fill the window with the specific color

eg:

[image]

How do i fill all the sides?

Any replies are greatly appreciated ;-)

Comment: If you are using `grid` manager then try `master.rowconfigure(0, weight =1)` and `master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)`. This will fill the entire window with any widget in row 0, column 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to also attach a minimal reproducible example. Nevertheless, I think you have put a `canvas` with the colour you want and expanded it to 1.

Canvases in Tkinter always have a border like thing. Rather you can use a `frame` with the same colour (instead of the canvas) and the border will disappear. The other option is to configure your root to have its own colour like such:

```
root.config(bg='red')
```

Either way, you will have to then delete your canvas and place its widgets into either the frame or the root itself.